# Perf does not annotate .c files called by Rust

Tags: c, rust, iperf

I am using perf to profile a rust application which calls some .c files. I want to annotate the .c functions. However in the perf report i can find only rust code annotated.

I have compiled the binaries using debug arguments( -g, -pg enabled). I have run the application as follows.

```
sudo perf record -pg --call-graph dwarf env RUST_BACKTRACE=full LD_LIBRARY_PATH="<Rust>/lib" ./target/release/<RustApp>
```

Can anyone please point out my mistake?

Comment: Please post platform-independent programming questions on [so].

Comment: @Melebius this does not necessarily sound like a generic question, but rather an issue with `perf`, which may or may not be a programming-related problem.  Issues with compiling a specific piece of software are also not necessarily "generic programming questions".